# get_user_model() fails in TastyPie's compat.py

Tags: django, tastypie

I am using python 3.3, Django 1.8 and Tastypie 0.11.1.

when I link everything and add tastypie as an installed application to settings.py of my project, trying to run `python manage.py shell` throws this error:

```
RuntimeError: App registry isn't ready yet.
```

I have read the reason behind this [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21875), and the explanation they provided. My understanding was that I should use `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` instead of `get_user_model()`. So I changed the code in `tastypie/compat.py` (source of the error) to use `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` instead, but now I get this error:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/tastypie/compat.py", line 16, in <module>
    username_field = User.USERNAME_FIELD
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'USERNAME_FIELD'
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Django 1.8 doesn't exist yet. 1.6 is the current version with 1.7 in beta.

Comment: dev is marked as 1.8, clone the project from github, query the version, and you will see it does exist ;)

Comment: `(1, 8, 0, 'alpha', 0)`, a very important difference from an official release.

Comment: I don't see how the discussion on django versions is relevant? I tried to make it clear the version which I have been using as I know it matters. asides that, the problem happens in the setting I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

First at all, show us your company.py code, please.

But, I guess you'r doing:

```
from django.config import settings
User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
```

And AUTH_USER_MODEL should be a String!

Because `AUTH_USER_MODEL = "myApp.CustomUser"` should be in your settings

You should do:

```
User = get_user_model()
```

This resolves the rigth User model according to settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL (i.e.import the right model)

Hope helps

Comment: `compat.py` is a file in tastypie (REST framework on top of Django) which is for compatibility. The original code uses `User = get_user_model()` which using this throws `App registry isn't ready yet.` Exception as I explained. The bug ticket (provided the link above) says it has to be replaced with `AUTH_USER_MODEL` but that doesn't work either and has type mismatch problem.

So the code is not my company's code, I am using tastypie's head, and I have this issue.